# X11 - Mouse simulation drag action

Tags: c++, mouseevent, mouse, x11

I simulate click and move actions using `XQueryPointer` and `XWarpPointer`. I want to simulate drag action but I can't find a way to do it. How can I do on linux machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [xtest](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/libXtst/xtestlib.html) extension - simulate initial mouse down + mouse move events + mouse up with `XTestFakeButtonEvent` / `XTestFakeMotionEvent`

Answer (score 1):

if you are not restricted to c++ you can also use xdotool. It's command line tool. For dragging you can send buttondown, move, buttonup events.